# Bad formatted XML with batch script

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch, 64-bit, xml

I have a batch script like below to create an XML file with specific structure and tags arrangement.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ROOTPATH=%~dp0
SET LINEBREAK=^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
SET "TAB=   "
SET /p COMPANY="Company Name: "
SET /p MODULE="Module Name: "
SET /p CODEPOOL="Code Pool: "
ECHO ^<?xml version="1.0"?^>"%LINEBREAK%"^<config^>"%LINEBREAK%""%TAB%"^<modules^>"%LINEBREAK%""%TAB%""%TAB%"^<"%COMPANY%_%MODULE%"^>"%LINEBREAK%""%TAB%""%TAB%""%TAB%"^<active^>true^</active^>"%LINEBREAK%""%TAB%""%TAB%""%TAB%"^<codePool^>local^</codePool^>"%LINEBREAK%""%TAB%""%TAB%"^</"%COMPANY%_%MODULE%"^>"%LINEBREAK%""%TAB%"^</modules^>"%LINEBREAK%"^</config^>>"%ROOTPATH%app\etc\modules\%COMPANY%_%MODULE%.xml"
PAUSE
```

Now I am aiming to create an XML file like below example XML code, with specific amount newlines and tab characters whenever necessary for indentation, also I know how to print the newline and tabs in batch files also as you have seen in the above given script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

But when I create the XML file, it actually is always badly formatted like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>"^SET "TAB=    ""<config>"^SET "TAB=   """"<modules>"^SET "TAB=    """"""<"Company_Module">"^SET "TAB= """"""""<active>true</active>"^SET "TAB=    """"""""<codePool>local</codePool>"^SET "TAB=   """"""</"Company_Module">"^SET "TAB=    """"</modules>"^SET "TAB=   ""</config>
```

Can someone let me know why this happens and how to solve it by batch code and standards only ?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter, I figured out the solution on my own by some googling for batch script character printing tricks.

I solved it by using `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` way in batch script.

Hope anyone having the same issue will find the below script useful:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ROOTPATH=%~dp0
SET \t= 
SET /p COMPANY="Company Name: "
SET /p MODULE="Module Name: "
SET /p CODEPOOL="Code Pool: "
(SET \n=^
%=DONT REMOVE THIS=%
)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO ^<?xml version="1.0"?^>!\n!^<config^>!\n!%\t%^<modules^>!\n!%\t%%\t%^<%COMPANY%_%MODULE%^>!\n!%\t%%\t%%\t%^<active^>true^</active^>!\n!%\t%%\t%%\t%^<codePool^>local^</codePool^>!\n!%\t%%\t%^</%COMPANY%_%MODULE%^>!\n!%\t%^</modules^>!\n!^</config^>>%ROOTPATH%app\etc\modules\%COMPANY%_%MODULE%.xml
ENDLOCAL
```

After using the above script with arguments: "Company1", "Module1", "local"; in that order, I generated below XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company1_Module1>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Company1_Module1>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Thanks anyway. If someone has better, shorter approach, feel free to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be in a single line? Using cmd, you can quickly run into the limitation for the line length that way. If using multiple lines is an option:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ROOTPATH=%~dp0
SET \t=   
SET /p COMPANY="Company Name: "
SET /p MODULE="Module Name: "
SET /p CODEPOOL="Code Pool: "

(
echo.^<?xml version="1.0"?^>
echo.^<config^>
echo.%\t%^<modules^>
echo.%\t%%\t%^<%COMPANY%_%MODULE%^>
echo.%\t%%\t%%\t%^<active^>true^</active^>
echo.%\t%%\t%%\t%^<codePool^>%CODEPOOL%^</codePool^>
echo.%\t%%\t%^</%COMPANY%_%MODULE%^>
echo.%\t%^</modules^>
echo.^</config^>
)>>%ROOTPATH%app\etc\modules\%COMPANY%_%MODULE%.xml
```

If you insist on using a single line, the delayedexpansion in combination with the new line character already is the most simple method. If you want to avoid delayedexpansion, there are also other ways to express the variable, as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7992971/8184542).